# Can't get switch to work

Tags: javascript, three.js

I can't get this switch to work also. Ideally, I would like to have to conditions like in the if else statement. The if else statement below it works but I can't figure out how to add 3 if's.

```
        function spriteAI1() {
        var posX = c2Sprite.position.x
        console.log(c2Sprite.position.x);
        switch(c2Sprite)
        {
        case c2Sprite.position.x > 30: 
        //&& c2Sprite.position.x <= 450:
        c2Sprite.translateX( -7 );
        break;
        //case c2Sprite.position.x < 30: 
        //&& c2Sprite.position.x >= -450:
        //c2Sprite.translateX( 7 );
        //break;
        //case c2Sprite.position.z < 30 
        //&& c2Sprite.position.x < 30:
        //c2Sprite.remove;
        //c2Sprite.clone;
        //break;
        //default: 
        //c2Sprite.translateX( -7 );
        //break;
               }
        }


                            function spriteAI2() {

            if (c2Sprite.position.z >= 30 && c2Sprite.position.z <= 350) { 
            c2Sprite.translateZ( -7 );
            } else if (c2Sprite.position.z <= -30 &&c2Sprite.position.z >= -350) {
            c2Sprite.translateZ( 7 );   
            } 
            //else (c2Sprite.position.z = 30 && c2Sprite.position.x = 30) { 
            //c2Sprite.remove;
            //c2Sprite.clone;
            //}
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` does not support comparisons.

When you `case c2Sprite.position.x > 30`, you're essentially comparing `case true` or `case false`, which `c2Sprite.position.x` is neither.

Consider switching to an `if` statement, like so:

```
if (c2Sprite.position.x > 30) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks if I do that then how to I get the if else under to work with more then too if's. when I add the second else it tells me I have an extra {

Comment: I could explain to you how to use the [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), but I cannot show you how, because you need to show that you have put in some effort into solving your own problem.

Comment: Yea I can understand that. Can you tell me what i'm doing wrong. Believe me I have put a lot of effort into this look at all the uncommitted code in the switch statement. And I only tried switching to the switch because I spent a few hours trying to figure out with my if statement wouldn't working.

Comment: @Brian it's not *exactly* true that `case` blocks don't support comparisons. The expressions can be anything, and they're evaluated as the `case` blocks are examined from first to last until a match is found. You're basically right however that it's a weird way to do a `switch`, and in this case it's syntactically OK but logically broken.